# Incorrect SO_REUSEADDR behavior on Linux

Tags: sockets, nat, hole-punching

There are two uses for SO_REUSEADDR:

- binding two servers on the same address (for server performance)
- binding a client then a server (for example for [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)))

It seems that the second one doesn't work on linux (I tested on RedHat and Chromium OS) although it works on macOS.

I made this little code:

```py
import socket

conn = socket.create_connection(("google.fr", 80))

if len(conn.getsockname()) == 2:
    family = socket.AF_INET
else:
    family = socket.AF_INET6

s = socket.socket(family)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
s.bind(conn.getsockname())
```

This code works on macOS but fails with `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` otherwise.

Is there any way to make it work? If not, where does this behavior come from?